# Что нужно сделать что бы открывались ссылки без окончания .js?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

Я хочу что бы у меня в адресной строке ссылка со скриптом открывалась не вот так

> site.com/script.js

а вот так

> site.com/script

но, когда пытаешь открыть без окончания .js то мне тут же предлагается скачать этот файл.

Comment: Если используется Apache веб-сервер, то можно использовать файл .htaccess и RewriteEngine:  

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.js -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.js

Comment: Для того чтобы содержимое скрипта сервилось текстом, надо устанавливать заголовок `Content-Type` в значение `text/javascript` или `text/plain`; А для вывода _результатов выполнения_ скриптов - необходимо настроить вызов node HTTP-сервером, с передачей интерпретатору полного пути файла (и тоже надо устанавливать заголовок с MIME-типом, соответствующим типу результата работы скрипта).